# Is this question really not constructive, if so how can I salvage it to get some answers?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

It's a bit old but I came to remember that I had [a question on non-standard RAID implementations](https://superuser.com/questions/315017/performance-and-reliability-aspects-of-non-standard-raid-implementations), which got shot down for being non-constructive. I do not agree with that assessment and would like to have a short discussion about it. I believe the question is not a shopping question, and it's not very subjective either. I am not asking for which one should I buy, or which one is better. I am interested in pros and cons of each system.

So, to re-iterate my questions:

- why is this question considered not constructive?
- if it really is not constructive, how can I salvage it to get some insight on the matter?

---

EDIT: To stress my claim; please take a look at this question and tell me how it's any different: [Which linux filesystem works best with SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/228657/which-linux-filesystem-works-best-with-ssd)

Comment: The current version of the questions seems like all any answer would be an extension of a discussion which makes it not very constructive on a Question and Answer type format.

Comment: The problem is you're trying to get a comparison of very obscure, specialized RAID implementations, each designed for a fairly specific purpose.  I think the creators of each RAID level provide more than adequate information for you to compare them yourself, for your particular use.

Comment: That was **almost 2 years ago** O__O Where were you?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg mostly on StackOverflow ^^. I was frustrated when the closing happened, so I wanted to calm down before writing about it, then I must have forgotten about the question. As I said I dont want to complain about the closing decision, I just want to know whether or not I can't salvage something out of that question

Comment: @posdef If it were me, I'd remove the junk about why you're buying it, it's not relevant. You would also need to explain what is not clear; what, after reading the Wiki link, was still unclear. This then becomes concise but as it stands it's a very open ended question IMO

Comment: @posdef - You are right there is little difference between the two questions.  Just because you found an open question with lots of upvotes doesn't mean its a good question.  It was also migrated to Superuser instead of being created on Superuser.

Comment: [This is a question](http://superuser.com/q/203186/47225) that I had on laptop battery tech when I needed to buy a new laptop battery.  Feel free to use this as an example on how to ask such questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could salvage this question by wording it as "What should I look for when considering proprietary RAID implementations?" and removing the references to specific NAS systems.

As it stands, your question is specific to a particular set of NAS/RAID systems, which tends to draw opinions in favor of or against a particular system.  This is why your question was closed as "not constructive".  In addition, this is very similar to a direct product recommendation question, [which is considered off topic](https://superuser.com/faq#questions).

In essence, you should be asking for **how** to find the product that suits you best, not **what** product to buy.  This quote sums it up:

> Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.